# flutter popUntil calls initState from last three routes

Tags: flutter, navigator

I have a question converning the "popUntil" method of flutters Navigator: Within my route "addFirst", I call

```
        Navigator.push(
        context,
        new PageRouteBuilder(
            maintainState: false,
            settings: RouteSettings(name: "addSecond"),
            pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, _, __) {
              return Addsecond();
            }));
```

to move over to "addSecond" route. From there, when tapping another button I again use

```
Navigator.push(
        context,
        new PageRouteBuilder(
            maintainState: false,
            pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, _, __) {
              return Addcontext();
            }));
```

to reach another route "addContext", where I tap another button and use

```
Navigator.push(context,
    new PageRouteBuilder(pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, _, __) {
  return ConfirmFaver();
}));
```

to reach my final route "ConfirmFaver". From there, I'd like to pop back until I reach my first route "addFirst", so I call:

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName("addFirst"));
```

Expected behaviour: Only the initState method from that "addFirst" route is called.
Actual behaviour: Not only show the logs that the initState method from "addFirst" is called, but afterwards also initState from "addSecond" and "addContext" are called.

Does anyone know why this happens? :)

Comment: Check [this tutorial](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-push-pop-push-1bb718b13c31)

Comment: Thanks Virendra. I know that specific tutorial, but I still cant figure out why .popUntil calls initState()-methods from last three routes. Do you know? :)